# xmppframework iphone groupchat getting "error code- 404, recipient-unavailable"

Tags: iphone, xmppframework

I have created new room for group chat by using this-

```
XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"viratsroom@conference.praveens-mac-mini.local"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];
if ([xmppRoom preJoinWithNickname:@"viratsRoom"]) {
  NSLog(@"room created");
  [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"viratsroom11" history:nil];
}
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:[self appDelegate] delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Room is getting created but with error

I have traced at server side and found this error-

```
     "presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="viratsroom@conference.iisd09/arup" to="arup@iisd09/ClientXMPP" type="error" error code="404" type="wait"  recipient-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Room wasnt configured properly hence all errors
calling this immediately after creating room doesnt work-

```
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm]; 
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
```

it takes a little time to create room after that u can configure the room.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(ConfigureNewRoom:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Thanks

Comment: i receive difference error code (400, bad request), but this code works for me, thanks

Comment: Better to just use the delegate method: -(void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender